# Why does unicode"decimalcode" not work?

Tags: solidity

According to the solidity documentation for unicode Literals:

> While regular string literals can only contain ASCII, Unicode literals
> – prefixed with the keyword unicode – ***can contain any valid UTF-8
> sequence***. They also support the very same escape sequences as
> regular string literals.

According to my understanding, ***any*** valid UTF-8 Sequence prefixed with "unicode", should result in the corresponding Unicode Sign.

However, neither

```
string example = unicode"226132128";
```

nor

```
string example = unicode"\u226132128";
```

is working

Note: 226132128 is the decimal sequence for the symbol ℀

could someone please explain me the mistake i am making?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have an answer why the decimal sequence does not result in ℀. Further, I am not quite sure if the decimal sequence actually represents ℀.
But the following two approaches work for solidity.

```
function readUnicode() external pure returns (string memory) {
    return "\u2100";
}
```

`\u2100` is Unicode Escape for ℀.

```
function readAnotherUnicode() external pure returns (string memory) {
    return unicode"℀";
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. unfortunately, my problem requires me to use decimal code, as i have to loop through a large number of unicode signs (and with letters inside the code this will result in a very high gas usage - as i have to concatinate the code instead of just incrementing a number)